# consecutive numbers with the same number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For n and n+1 both have the same number of divisors k, with k>3.  Given any k will there always be an infinite number of n's?

Comment: Possibly related: https://msp.org/pjm/1987/129-2/pjm-v129-n2-p06-s.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No, there will not be for prime $k$.  For prime $k$ there will not be any.  For prime $k$ the only way to have $k$ divisors is to be of the form $p^{k-1}$ for $p$ prime.  As there are no successive squares, cubes, or any other power except $0$ and $1$ there are none.

For $k=4$ a number can have four factors if it is the cube of a prime or the product of two different primes.  As one of $n,n+1$ is even, one of the primes must be $2$, so we are looking for $2p=qr\pm 1$ with $p,q,r$ prime or $2p=q^3\pm 1$. $q^3\pm 1=(q\pm 1)(q^2\mp q+1)$ so the only possibility here is $26,27$

Comment: That has narrowed the question to those number of divisors that are allowed.  I am thinking of (say) k=6, as in 44,45 or 75,76.  Would all allowable number of divisors produce an endless number of n's? If the number of divisors were 3*6*8=144, with great difficulty n and n+1 could be found indefinitely--is this true?

Comment: There may be an infinite number with $k=4$.  Certainly there are $(14,15),(34,35),(38,39)$.  They are easy to search for.  Multiply two odd primes, add or subtract $1$ to get a number $2 \bmod 4$ and see if it is twice a prime.

Comment: I experimented for k=6 and found that 2^2 and 3^2 are the most common primes found.  For larger k I guess this is a question not easily answered. Think  that for some large k there  exists the largest one and then none after that...sort of like Waring stuff.

Comment: So that would be $2^2p=3^2q\pm 1$ with $p,q$ prime?  It makes sense to me.  If you just search up to some limit, there are more numbers with $2^2$ and $3^2$ than any other square divisors.

Comment: Yes, that is correct for k=6.  I did a further experiment by using two such numbers in an unusual convolution using four different methods and finding the sum of all such convolutions.  Three of the results compared to the total of all four results have the proportions 30%, 30%, and 40%; the smallest result contributes under 2%.  No doubt there are some sequences for OEIS in this question.

Comment: It exist at OEIS at http://oeis.org/A005237.  Still for large k I guess we are still in the dark about the infinitude of such consecutive numbers.

Comment: That series has $n,n+1$ with the same number of divisors, but gathers together all the $n$ regardless of the number of divisors.  The paper Matthew Conroy linked to shows that up to large $x$ there are at least $x(\log \log x)^{-3}$ such numbers

Comment: http://oeis.org/A039832 has the solutions for $k=4$  There is no mention whether the series is infinite.

Comment: This x(loglogx) to the minus 3 makes no sense.  The infinitude then would still be uncertain.  The trouble with integers is that there are too many of them.

Comment: No, it shows the numbers are infinite because $x$ grows so much faster than $(\log \log x)^{3}$

Comment: By x you mean the number of divisors of an integer and not the integer?  Also you first wrote x(loglogx) to the MINUS three then as the plus three.  The former would mean that this reciprocal is always LESS than unity.  Such are the liabilities of e-mail math.